# formatting in server tag for datalist binding

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, datalist

what I am writing on aspx page is

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
 NavigateUrl="~/Comp/Default.aspx?abc=71&xyz=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TeamId") %>"
>
```

in hope to create a hyperlink in resulting mark up, but its giving error in parsing.

I tried all possible combination of quotation marks and angular brackets, nothing helped.

Comment: The markup

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Comp/Default.aspx?abc=71&xyz=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TeamId") %>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm missing `/>` at the end
2. You have a quote(`""`) issue
3. i would use `String.Format` instead

---

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Comp/Default.aspx?abc={0}&xyz={1}", Eval("id"), Eval("TeamId")) %>' 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the above works, with the new *Model Binding* feature from .NET 4.5 you can also use the `Item.` binding.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
  NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Comp/Default.aspx?abc={0}&xyz={1}", Item.id, Item.TeamId) %>' 
/>
```

(As long ans you don't mix up the quotation marks of course)